# Using OAuth2 tokens for interactive usage of GCP services instead of service account (keys)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In order to limit the number of service accounts to manage as well as handling their keys, I'm exploring other ways of accessing GCP resources from a developer laptop or desktop so I can run ad-hoc scripts or interactive programs (e.g. Jupyter notebook) that access GCP services.

Using `gcloud auth application-default login` generates, after authenticating via a web browser, a refresh token that can be used to get and renew access tokens that can be used to interact with GCP services.

The workflow I'm following is this:

1. Run `gcloud auth application-default login`. This generates a JSON file on my disk that
   contains the refresh token.
2. Export the JSON file location as `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable
   `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/my.username/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`
3. Use that file to authenticate via Google auth library and interact with different GCP services.

This is convenient, as it reduces the need to circulate, secure and, if needed, share service account key files around team members. However, I have noticed that the refresh token provided does not expire and is still valid.

Unless I'm missing something here, this makes `application_default_credentials.json` file as sensitive as a service account key. If it gets lost or compromised it can be used to get access tokens without the need to re-authenticate, which is fairly insecure, IMO.

We're aware of the GCP security best practices recommend using service account (and their keys) for *service-to-service* workloads. This scenario I'm describing is for ad-hoc, development/testing of code from
a developer's or engineer's laptop. We think that forcing users to interactively authenticate via the web to get new tokens every few hours would be more secure and convenient than using long-lived service account keys stored in the hard drive.

I have read through [1] but I could not find a definitive answer.

- Does anyone know if there is an expiration for these refresh tokens?
- Is there a way of controlling and limiting their lifetimes (ideally to hours or minutes)?
- What is the best/common practice for this scenario? Using a single service account (and key) per individual user?

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration

Answer (score 1):

Note: User Credentials have Refresh Tokens too.

> Does anyone know if there is an expiration for these refresh tokens?

Google OAuth Refresh Tokens do not expire. They can be revoked.

> Is there a way of controlling and limiting their lifetimes (ideally to
>   hours or minutes)?

You could periodically revoke the Refresh Token which will invalidate the Access and Client ID tokens. This means that you are handling the Refresh Tokens which adds another security issue to manage.

> What is the best/common practice for this scenario? Using a single
>   service account (and key) per individual user?

If you use User Credentials (the method where you log in to Google) you will receive SDK warnings and if you make a lot of API calls, you will become blocked. Google does not want you to use User credentials in place of Service Account credentials. The verification process for User Credentials requires more effort on Google's backend systems. User Credentials are assumed to be created in an insecure environment (web browsers) whereas Service Account credentials are assumed to be in a secure environment.

Best practices are to issue service account JSON key files to an individual application with only the required permissions for that application to operate. For example, if you create a tool that only needs to read Cloud Storage objects, create a service account with only read permissions. Periodically the service account keys should be rotated and new keys downloaded and old keys deleted. Each application should have its own service account JSON key file. I wrote an article on how to securely store JSON key files on Cloud Storage. This helps with rotating keys as your application just downloads the latest key when needed. ([link](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-go-identity-based-access-control/)). My article discusses Google Cloud Run, but the same principles apply.

Comment: `Best practices are to issue service account JSON key files to an individual application with only the required permissions for that application to operate.` I'm 100% onboard with that, but my question is more about _users_ (humans) interacting with, say, GCS or BigQuery via a script or similar tool. It would be quite impractical having to create a separate service account (+keys) with the same permissions they already have in IAM for each one of them. The solution you describe in your blog post (nice write up, BTW) relies on accessing and using a shared service account  key.

Comment: You can use User Account credentials. However, read my warning about being API limited if you use User Account credentials where you should use service accounts. The Cloud SDK will display a warning message which may confuse your users. If you read another article, I show how to use User Credentials to generate both Access Tokens and Identity Tokens. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-and-go-my-journey-to-learn-a-new-language-in-30-days/#day_08